# Can I set the "Archive" bit on a file on NTFS on Linux?

Tags: linux, filesystems, ntfs

On a NTFS file system, you can set the `Archive` bit for a file.

I can set the `Archive` bit for a file on a NTFS partition if I am using Windows, but say that I have a NTFS partition mounted on Linux, can I set the `Archive` bit for a file on Linux also?

Comment: To avoid being too broad, I’d suggest making this question specific to ntfs, so that answers could specify what features are currently enabled.

Answer (score 2):

The most popular tool, named `ntfs-3g` supports this capability. It's named **NTFS attributes**.

You should ensure `setfattr` ([man 1 setfattr](https://linux.die.net/man/1/setfattr)) is installed. NTFS attributes constitute two groups of attributes: `system.ntfs_attrib` (*small-endian*) and `system.ntfs_attrib_be`(*big-endian*). It's just for convenient usage.

Each attribute is presented by it's own HEX value (i.e. `0x20` for `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ARCHIVE`). More info and values you can see at the [official resource](http://jp-andre.pagesperso-orange.fr/extend-attr.html). NTFS attributes group consist of 4 bytes within that you can combine several attributes (Archive + System ...).

Display current NTFS attributes of `test.file`:

```
# Big-Endian
getfattr -h -e hex -n system.ntfs_attrib_be source-file
```

Set `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ARCHIVE` for `test.file`:

```
# Big-Endian.
setfattr -h -v 0x00000020 -n system.ntfs_attrib_be target-file

# Little-Endian (in this manner in x86 family CPU bytes are stored.
# IMHO it's not very convenient for usage.
setfattr -h -v 0x20000000 -n system.ntfs_attrib target-file
```