# Does Linux have system calls to access all the features of the file systems it supports?

Tags: linux, filesystems

Linux supports many file systems (for example: ext3, NTFS, FAT32, etc.).

The following diagram shows how Linux allows a process to access files:

[image]

So assume that a process called the `read()` system call to read a file, what will happen is that the VFS layer will be accessed, and the VFS layer will decide which file system driver to access based on the file system of the partition that the file to be read resides on.

Linux provides many system calls to access files (for example: `read()`, `write()`, `rename()`, etc.).

Now `read()` and `write()` and `rename()` work on all the file systems that Linux supports.

But there are specific features that exist only on some file systems while not existing on others. For example: on a NTFS file system, you can set the *Archive* bit for a file, while this can't be done on an ext3 file system.

Now my question is, does Linux have system calls to access all the features of the file systems it supports? for example: does Linux have a system call to set the *Archive* bit for a file on a NTFS file system?

Answer (score 11):

> does Linux have a system call to set the Archive bit for a file on a NTFS file system?

For this particular case, the `ntfs-3g` driver exports the file attributes via [extended attributes](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/xattr.7.html), see [Can I set the "Archive" bit on a file on NTFS on Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/437126/170373)

The (V)FAT file system has the similar file attributes, but it uses an `ioctl()` function to access them, see [`ioctl_fat(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ioctl_fat.2.html). (`ioctl()` is a sort of a multipurpose system call, used for all kinds of device specific stuff that don't warrant a real system call.)

> Now my question is, does Linux have system calls to access all the features of the file systems it supports?

It's hard to answer *for sure*, but there has been at least one example of the opposite. ext4 internally supports a "birth time" timestamp for files (like, a real creation time, unlike `ctime` that changes on inode modification). But even though ext4 is the "standard" filesystem, for a long time, there was no system call to access the birth time.

It should be supported now, with the [`statx()` system call](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/statx.2.html) added in [Linux 4.11](https://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_4.11), in April 2017.

Related:

- [Birth is empty on ext4](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50177/birth-is-empty-on-ext4)
- A number of articles on lwn.net about statx, including e.g. [statx() v3](https://lwn.net/Articles/707602/)

Comment: ntfs != fat. At least the kernel version of ntfs does NOT have any way to set or get the archive flag, though its headers define it. Only the fuse based ntfs-3g seems to support it (via extended attributes, not special ioctls).

Comment: This isn’t directly related to the question, but as a complement to your mention of `statx`, it’s now supported in the C library and in the latest version of coreutils which was released a few days ago.

Comment: @UncleBilly, d'oh, apparently I can't read, but just automatically thought of (v)fat. Thanks for noticing that, I'll see if I can find a more appropriate reference.